# Azure Powershell version 5.1.1 issue while working with Azure Storage Tables

Tags: powershell, azure

When we try to insert an entity in azure storage table, we get the following error:

Script

```
$entity = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,$assemblySN" -ArgumentList $PartitionKey, $RowKey
$result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($entity))
```

Error

> Cannot convert argument "operation", with value: "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation", for "Execute"
>   to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation": "Cannot convert the
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation" value of type
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation"."

Analysis

As per the release of Azure Powershell version 5.1.1, it has upgraded Azure Storage Client Library 8.6.0.0 (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll) 
but it also keeping the older version (v8.1.1.0).

So, there are two libraries with the same name but the different version. The lower version (v8.1.1.0) 
which is present under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Storage 
and the higher version (v8.6.0.0) file present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\Storage\Azure.Storage

In order to perform operations on Azure Storage Tables, v8.6.0.0 is the one which is required to deal with all the Azure Storage Table Operations. 
By default, any object for example like below uses the file located in AzureRm.Storage folder -

Assembly                                                                                        ------
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is specify the version to be aligned with PowerShell Azure.Storage module when new the object:

```
$temp = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

**Note:** In latest PowerShell 5.1.1, it will be 8.6.0; in the before PowerShell version, the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version is different.

For more details, refer “[#5030](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5030)”.